# How to check if a is a number power of 2

Tags: r, dataframe, validation, filter, data-science

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to know if which values of my column in my dataframe are power of two.
My data is a dataframe with 6 columns, one of the columns has the values that I want to check if the numbers are power of 2.

`class(df$doubling_times)  > numeric`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`log2(x) %% 1 == 0` - checks if the log base 2 of the number is an integer (when divided by 1, is the remainder 0?)

```
> x = 1:10
> data.frame(x, power2 = log2(x) %% 1 == 0)
    x power2
1   1   TRUE
2   2   TRUE
3   3  FALSE
4   4   TRUE
5   5  FALSE
6   6  FALSE
7   7  FALSE
8   8   TRUE
9   9  FALSE
10 10  FALSE
```

The above should work, but a safer approach would allow for floating point accuracy issues, and might be something like this:

```
remainder = log2(x) %% 1
tol = 1e-12 # tolerance
power2 = abs(remainder - round(remainder)) < tol
```

Comment: The [R FAQ 7.31 is found here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f): Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?